# Multiple list items with comma separated in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code.

```
<div class="form-multiassign-add  binded" id="property_groupids">
        <div class="form-multiselectbox wide4 assigned">
            <div class="title"><div class="pad5-left pad5-top left font13">Selected Properties</div>
            <div class="button action right addbutton binded" id="addbutton"><i class="add"></i> Add</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
            <li id="selected-property_groupids-484645" data-listid="484645" data-all-properties="admin" style="background:#E5E5E5;">
            <label><i class="delete" title="Remove"></i>00New</label><input type="hidden" name="property_group[][ids]" value="484645"></li>
            <li id="selected-property_groupids-21458" data-listid="21458" data-all-properties="admin" style="background:#E5E5E5;">
            <label><i class="delete" title="Remove"></i>13th North Avenue</label><input type="hidden" name="property_group[][ids]" value="21458"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I want only ids of li. After addbutton link click, new li gets added.
**Required result -**

```
<input type="hidden" id="selected_li_ids" value="484645,21458" />
```

I try it like this -

```
$('#property_groupids .ui-sortable li').each(function(){
    ids[] = $(this).data('listid');
 });
$('#selected_li_ids').val(ids);
```

But it won't work. Any help.

Comment: `$('#property_groupids .ui-sortable li').map(function(){ return $(this).data('listid'); }).get()` would return an array of listids

Comment: Look at the error message in your console.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
var ids = [];
$('#property_groupids .ui-sortable li').each(function(i,e){
    ids.push($(e).data('listid'));
});
$('#selected_li_ids').val(ids.join(","));
```

considering @freedomn-m suggestion:

```
ids = $.map($('#property_groupids .ui-sortable li'),function(n, i){
    return $(n).data('listid');
});
idsString = Object.values(ids).join(",");
$('#selected_li_ids').val(idsString);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need the attribute `data-listid`.

```js
var ids = [];
$("li").each(function(){
ids.push($(this).attr("data-listid"));
});

//put hidden instead of text
$("#property_groupids").append('<input type="text" id="selected_li_ids" value="'+ids.join(",")+'" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-multiassign-add  binded" id="property_groupids">
        <div class="form-multiselectbox wide4 assigned">
            <div class="title"><div class="pad5-left pad5-top left font13">Selected Properties</div>
            <div class="button action right addbutton binded" id="addbutton"><i class="add"></i> Add</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
            <li id="selected-property_groupids-484645" data-listid="484645" data-all-properties="admin" style="background:#E5E5E5;">
            <label><i class="delete" title="Remove"></i>00New</label><input type="hidden" name="property_group[][ids]" value="484645"></li>
            <li id="selected-property_groupids-21458" data-listid="21458" data-all-properties="admin" style="background:#E5E5E5;">
            <label><i class="delete" title="Remove"></i>13th North Avenue</label><input type="hidden" name="property_group[][ids]" value="21458"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```